# HTML5 text editor for CSS

Tags: jquery, html, html-editor

I am looking for HTML5 Text editor plugin which will work on CSS
(*i.e not generate/manipulate a HTML content*).

I have seen many editors like [summernote](https://summernote.org/), 
[ckeditor](https://ckeditor.com/), [WYSIWYG HTML Editor](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor) and so on and everyone is inserting an HTML tag for *e.g*:
If I want to make heading bold they will insert string tag - but I need style to be manipulated it should add CSS saying `font-weight:700`.

Please let me know if that kind of editor is available or not.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, no. There may be a plugin for Wordpress itself which would allow this.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much all available WYSIWYG editors use the `contentEditable` browser features, which use inline style in elements, and much to my annoyance deprecated elements such as `<font>` and `<b>` (instead of `<strong>`).

I'm one of the Contributing members of Summernote, and this is something that we're currently looking at working on by building our own DOM functions.